# Error a la hora de modificar archivos de texto

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando realizar sqli sobre varios laboratorios web) y estoy intentando modificar
las variables de la url pero, a la hora de intentar modificar los parámetros de la url en un archivo de texto, no consigo modificar el texto entre "=" y "&".

El error es:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

El código:

```
links_To_Process = open('links.txt','r+')
for link in links_To_Process:
    key_1 = "="
    key_2 = "&"
    position_Key_1 = link.find(key_1)
    position_Key_2 = link.find(key_2)
    if position_Key_1 == -1:
        pass
    else:
        if position_Key_2 < position_Key_1:
            pass
        else:
            position_len = len(range(position_Key_1,position_Key_2))
            if position_Key_2 != position_Key_1:
                var = int(position_Key_2 - position_len)
                for x in var:
                    link.replace(x,"'")
                print(link)
```

Comment: Tu variable `var` es un entero ya que la obtienes así `var = int(position_Key_2 - position_len)` y por lo tanto no puede iterarla.

Comment: Del mismo modo que si la convierto a tipo cadena, devuelve error (TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str').

Comment: Inclusive, he cambiado parte del código:
     <code>
var = str(position_Key_2 - position_len)
     link.replace(str(var),"'")
     print(link)
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que no funciona es porque `var` es un entero y los enteros no son iterables, aún convirtiendolo a `string` vas a obtener un `string` de un número y lo que necesitas es la parte intermedia del texto.

Para reemplazar una parte del `string` lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `slices`, de esa forma puedes "armar" nuevamente el `string` con los caracteres que deseas reemplazar.

**Nota:** Como no agregaste algunas filas de tus datos cree un arreglo con datos genéricos para mostrar el funcionamiento.

Ejemplo:

```
links_To_Process = ['=abc&', 'def&', 'g=hi&']
for link in links_To_Process:
    key_1 = "="
    key_2 = "&"
    
    # Cadena que se utilizará para reemplazar los caracteres
    # entre las llaves
    rep_str = "'"
    position_Key_1 = link.find(key_1)
    position_Key_2 = link.find(key_2)
    if position_Key_1 == -1:
        pass
    else:
        if position_Key_2 < position_Key_1:
            pass
        else:
            if position_Key_2 != position_Key_1:
                # Obtener el número de caracteres entre la llave 1 y la llave 2
                var = int(position_Key_2 - position_Key_1 - 1)
                
                # Reemplazar los caracteres intermedios por la cadena definida en rep_str
                link = link[0:position_Key_1+1] + (rep_str * var) + link[position_Key_2:]
                print(link)
```

Cuando segmentamos (Utilizamos `slice`) en una cadena los parámetros son:

```
cadena[indice inicial (incluyente): indice final (excluyente): paso]
```

Para más información sobre los `slices` puedes leer [éste artículo.](https://cupi2-ip.github.io/IPBook/nivel3/seccion3-4.html#:%7E:text=La%20expresi%C3%B3n%20slicing%20hace%20referencia,dentro%20de%20la%20secuencia%20original.)

Comment: Y en el caso de querer borrar el resto del contenido desde el igual?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al respecto? ¿Qué errores te devuelve?

Comment: if position_Key_2 < position_Key_1:
    link = link[0:position_Key_1+1] + (rep_str * 1)

Comment: Increiblemente me ha funcionado, sin errores.